# Find two elements of the array such that their absolute difference is not greater than a given integer but is as close to the said integer

Tags: javascript

if i replace new_one (`var new_one=Math.max(Math.abs(array[i]- array[j]),return new_one)`); with `max_value` result will be false?

```js
function absolute_difference(array, num) {
  var new_one = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
      if ((Math.abs(array[i] - array[j])) <= num) {
        var new_one = Math.max(Math.abs(array[i] - array[j]), new_one);
      }
    }
  }
  return new_one;
}
console.log(absolute_difference([12, 10, 33, 34], 24));
```

Comment: do you have some examples with the wanted result?

Comment: function different_values(ara, n) {
    var max_val = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < ara.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < ara.length; j++) {
            var x = Math.abs(ara[i] - ara[j]);
            if (x <= n) {
                max_val = Math.max(max_val, x)
            }
        }
    }
    return max_val
}
console.log(different_values([12, 10, 33, 34], 24));

Comment: Edit the question to add that code where you can format it. Blobs of code in comments are very hard to read

Comment: "*Find two elements ...*" do you need to return the two elements?

Comment: @NinaScholz i replaced new_one( one of them is in if block and the other one by return )with max_val,so result became 1 instead of 24

Comment: we can't really understand your issue without, at least, giving us a result that you would have.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the delta and check against the wanted value and if delta is greater than the last max value. Then store the values and the local max value.

```js
function absolute_difference(array, num) {
    var pair,
        max = -1,
        delta;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {     // adjust length
        for (var j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            delta = Math.abs(array[i] - array[j]);
            if (delta <= num && delta > max) {
                 pair = [array[i], array[j]];
                 max = delta;
            }
        }
    }
    return pair;
}

console.log(absolute_difference([12, 10, 33, 34], 24));
```